# How can I prove/disprove that the function $f(x)$ satifies $f'(c)=1$ for certain conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The function is defined on the interval $[0,1]$ with following conditions:
1) $f(0)=1$,
2) $f(1)=2$,
3) $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$,
Prove or disprove: There exists some $c$ from $(0,1)$, such that $f'(c)=1$.

My work so far:
If we assume that $f(x)$ is also differentiable on $(a,b)$ than due to Mean Value Theorem we have

$f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=\frac{2-1}{1}=1$,

therefore everything holds. But if I exclude this assumption I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hint: The fact that you have to assume differentiability in order to use the MVT suggests that a non-differentiable function might supply a counterexample.

Comment: I think Weierstrass function can be accordingly  modified to give a counterexample:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: @Timbuc: That is **far** more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Yes, now I see that, @BrianM.Scott...way more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $f$ need not be differentiable, you can make $f$ piecewise linear with two pieces.

Comment: are you hinting at the fact that $\;f\;$ *can be constructed*? Because I think the OP meant hte function *is given* .

Comment: @Timbuc: I take the question to be asking whether the hypotheses imply that such a $c$ exists. They don’t, since counterexamples exist, and I’m suggesting how one can easily be constructed. If the question is about a specific $f$, obviously we would have to know what that function is.

Comment: Oh, I see @Brian. Thank you. BTW, excellent way to construct a counter example. +1

Comment: @Timbuc: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, I got it, it is actually trivial.

Comment: @Timbuc I also first thought that, but I don't think that the approach would work because of $f(0)=1$. If we have $f(x)=\sum a^n cos(b^n\pi x)$, than for $f(0)=1$ we get $\sum a^n=1$ which leads to $\frac{1}{1-a} =1$ which in turn makes $a=0$.

Comment: @eye: You’re welcome.